# apply_gradients for tensorflow optimizers

Tags: tensorflow

The tensorflow documentation states that:

> Calling minimize() takes care of both computing the gradients and
>   applying them to the variables. If you want to process the gradients
>   before applying them you can instead use the optimizer in three steps:
>
> Compute the gradients with compute_gradients(). Process the gradients
>   as you wish. Apply the processed gradients with apply_gradients().

However the example given is for vanilla SGD. 
Does this two step process work for other types of optimizers (like momentum, adam etc), which don't use the gradients directly but instead use other derived descent directions ?

If so, where do the various intermediate variables and the final descent direction get computed - in compute_gradients or apply_gradients ?

Thanks.

Comment: It works for other types of optimization and the final descent direction is computed in `apply_gradients`

Comment: Is it possible to get (and summarize) the actual descent direction that is used ?

Comment: Actual descent direction is not exposed. As a work-around, you can apply the gradients to 0 vector to get the direction, or look at difference between two successive points